# How to convert nodejs writeDoubleBE buffer to c# double?

Tags: c#, node.js, buffer

I have a nodejs Buffer of `writeDoubleBE`. how to convert it to `C#` double upon receiving the byte array?

nodejs Code like this:

```
var b1 = new Buffer(8);
b1.writeDoubleBE(123.123456789,0);
```

now what is the equivalent of `b1` in `c#`?

Answer (score 0):

All windows x64/x86 are little endian systems, so after you get in C# your byte array you should reverse your big endian byte order:

```
double b1 = BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes.Reverse().ToArray(), 0);
```

If you run on `Mono` somewhere else you can use `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` to check if you need to reverse the array.

And the equivalent double serializer would be:

```
double x = 1.1;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    // on windows `IsLittleEndian` would be always true
    bytes = bytes.Reverse().ToArray()
}
```